# Google Tag Manager (GTM) virtual pageview doesn't show in Google Analytics (GA)

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've created a GA tag in GTM.  It has "Enable overriding" checked.  The Field Name is the Page Path built-in variable, and the value is "/register".

So the goal is for this tag to send a virtual pageview when triggered to GA with the page path value of "/register".

I can see the tag is triggered on the website at registration in debug view.  However, I do not see any pageviews in GA with the name of "/register".

I've read every guide I can find, but can't figure out what to try next to get this to work..
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the wrong value for `Field Name`. If you change `{{Page Path}}` to `page` that will start sending virtual pageviews.

Comment: That seems to make sense.  I did change it, but I still haven't seen the virtual page events make it through to Google Analytics.  The trigger is definitely firing, and the link between GTM and GA seems to be generally working ok.

Comment: Do you have any filters set on your view? These may be discarding or distorting the data

Answer (score 1):

You are doing 2 mistakes.

1. The right field to set is **page** and not {{Page Path}}
2. When you are selecting "override" make sure to put the UA ID
   directly on the field, OR make a new constant variable maybe by name
   "GA UA ID" put your GA ID over there and than select that variable
   under override tracking id field. You are selecting the same GA
   settings variable that is causing the issue if you still not seeing
   after updating the field settings